# asp.net MVC3 JQuery hidden field not being posted

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

note that the code works fine on my machine but when published to my hosting provider the hidden data is not being posted

I have a form where you set the address, google maps then gets the lat/lng and jquery will set the value in the hidden field

but when posted the value are not sent to the server

I even tried Request["Lat"] and nothing is sent

When running the same code on my local machine it works fine, could it be a configuration problem? I don't see it.

Thanks

here is part of the code
webpage

```
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register","Account")) // same error without the action and controller specified

....
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new { maxlength = "200" })
.....
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Lat)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Lng)
....
```

in js

```
...
$('#Address').blur(function () {
        $('#Address').val($('#Address').val().toUpperCase());
        codeAddress();
        drawCircle();
    });
...
function codeAddress() {
    if ($('#Address').val() == '')
        return;

    var address = $('#Address').val() + ', CA';
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $('#Lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#Lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                //alert($('#Lat').val() + ', ' +$('#Lng').val())
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                drawCircle();
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
....
```

at this point the alert shows the new lat,lng

when posted the default 0 of empty is posted

My question is why would it always work on my dev machine and not on my shared hosting?

UPDATE : it seems like the defaultbinder is not binding, why would it work locally but not on live server?

New Update:
Actually the form is being posted I can see in firebug
My controller says that no form data was received though
my log indicates no post data

it happens also on the log on, where only username, password and remember me are sent 
any idea would help

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, @sResources.Strings.LogOnUnsuccessful)
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account"))
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { style = " width:200px" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { style = " width:200px" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="@sResources.Strings.LogOn" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}


       [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult LogOn()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
            {
                //LogOnModel model = new LogOnModel() { UserName = UserName, Password = Password, RememberMe = RememberMe.HasValue ? RememberMe.Value : false };
                if (model != null)
                    Log(new Exception(string.Format("model username : {0}, password : {1}, request[username] {2} , request[password] : {3}", model.UserName, model.Password, Request["UserName"], Request["Password"])));
                try...
```

where model.UserName and model.Password is empty

why is the model empty

Comment: *probably* something is wrong with the paths

Answer (score 1):

Load up fiddler and look for the field being posted. If it's not there then inspect the form elements value in the browsers developer tools. If it's not set then it won't get posted. Also when you deployed it note that cross domain frames can't read each others data so if you are trying to read a frame or iframes value from a different tilt domain this will fail.

Comment: When i do an alert in the js just after getting the info from the geocoder the info is set properly in the hidden fields. I am not using frames, i'm posting a form back to my site. The other problem is that it seems to be random, sometimes you can register sometimes you may not.

Comment: Ah ok I wonder if the lat decimal format isn't binding? Check out http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

Comment: seems like the problem could be with client side validation i have now disabled <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/>        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"/> but on my production server it still fails as sometimes the form is posted empty and sometimes the validation blocks the submit even if the form is valid, that is how i got it to work on my windows 7 home premium